# Richtige Stellung des Korrelats

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, infinitive, pronominal-adverb

Wenn wir einen Objektsatz als Präpositionalphrase eines Adjektivs haben, brauchen wir manchmal ein Korrelat, ein Präpositionaladverb.
Meine Frage ist sehr einfach: Gibt es eine Regel, um vorherzusagen, welche Stellung für dieses Präpositionaladverb oder Korrelat die richtige ist?

Siehe dazu folgende Beispiele:

> Ich bin **daran** interessiert, dass sie das Haus kaufen.
>
> Er war wild **darauf**, sie kennen zu lernen.
>
> Er war nicht **dazu** befugt, die Dokumente mitzunehmen.
>
> Er war nicht befugt, die Dokumente mitzunehmen.

Korrelat fakultativ:

> Ich bin Ihnen sehr dankbar **dafür**, dass Sie mich unterstützt haben.

Wie kann ich die richtige Stellung des Korrelats bestimmen, wenn es nötig ist – nach dem Adjektiv oder davor?

Answer (score 4):

Meistens sind beide Stellungen möglich, die (semantische) Betonung wird allenfalls leicht anders gelegt. Auch die Betonung- und Negationspartikeln *sehr* und *nicht* können verschoben werden:

> Ich bin interessiert **daran**, dass sie das Haus kaufen.
>
> Er war **darauf** wild, sie kennenzulernen.
>
> Er war nicht befugt **dazu**, die Dokumente mitzunehmen.
>   Er war **dazu** nicht befugt, die Dokumente mitzunehmen.
>
> Ich bin Ihnen **dafür** sehr dankbar, dass Sie mich unterstützt haben.
>   Ich bin Ihnen sehr **dafür** dankbar, dass Sie mich unterstützt haben.

Dasselbe gilt für die (hier angenäherten) Alternativen mit einfachen Präpositionen:

> Ich bin **am Hauskauf** interessiert.
>   Ich bin interessiert **am Hauskauf**.
>
> Er war wild **auf das Kennenlernen**.
>   Er war **auf das Kennenlernen** wild.
>
> Er war nicht **zur Mitnahme** befugt.
>   Er war nicht befugt **zur Mitnahme**.
>   Er war **zur Mitnahme** nicht befugt.
>
> Ich bin Ihnen sehr dankbar **für die Unterstützung**.
>   Ich bin Ihnen **für die Unterstützung** sehr dankbar.
>   Ich bin Ihnen sehr **für die Unterstützung** dankbar.

Die Satzinitialstellung funktioniert leicht anders und ist in der Schriftsprache für die komplexen Infinitive unüblich, während sie im Mündlichen eine häufige Art der Hervorhebung ist.

> **Am Hauskauf** bin ich interessiert.
>   Dass sie das Haus kaufen, **daran** bin ich interessiert.
>
> **Auf das Kennenlernen** war er wild.
>   Sie kennenzulernen, **darauf** war er wild.
>
> **Zur Mitnahme** war er nicht befugt.
>   Die Dokumente mitzunehmen, **dazu** war er nicht befugt.
>
> **Für die Unterstützung** bin ich Ihnen sehr dankbar.
>   Dass Sie mich unterstützt haben, **dafür** bin ich bin Ihnen sehr dankbar.

Schlussendlich gibt es in manchen Dialekten (und nicht in der stilvollen Schriftsprache) die Möglichkeit, das *da* abzutrennen bzw. zu duplizieren, was sowohl verstärkende Funktion haben als auch völlig neutral-normal sein kann. In diesem Fall steht das *da* immer links. Verkürzungen von *dar-* zu *dr-* sind häufig fakultativ und verbleiben zwingend bei den mit Vokal beginnenden Präpositionen. Wenn eine Modalpartikel wie *sehr* oder *nicht* vorkommt, kann die Präposition ebenfalls links stehen:

> Ich bin **da** interessiert **dran**, dass sie das Haus kaufen.
>
> Er war **da** wild **drauf**, sie kennen zu lernen.
>
> Er war **da** nicht **zu** befugt, die Dokumente mitzunehmen.
>   Er war **da** nicht befugt **zu**, die Dokumente mitzunehmen.
>
> Ich bin Ihnen **da** sehr dankbar **für**, dass Sie mich unterstützt haben.
>   Ich bin Ihnen **da** sehr **für** dankbar, dass Sie mich unterstützt haben.